# Method not being recognized even when declared

Tags: java

So, I am creating a project of a basic "arcade". I have cards which are passed into games(methods). I created a method in my Card class to have the ability to chose which cards to use for the games.

```
public Card choosecard(Card firstCard, Card secondCard) {

   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

   Card chosen = new Card();
   boolean check = false;

   while(check == false) {

   System.out.println("What card would you like to use?\n  1. " + firstCard.name + "\n  2. " + secondCard.name);
   int answer = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());

   if(answer == 1) {
       chosen = firstCard;
       check = true;
   }
   else if(answer == 2) {
       chosen = secondCard;
       check = true;
   }
   else {

   }

   } //while

   return chosen;
```

After creating this method I tried calling it in this context:

```
public static void terminal(Card card1, Card card2) {

    boolean loop = true;
    while(loop == true) {

    System.out.println("What would you like to do?\n1. Guess Game\n2. Transfer\n3. Prizes\n4. Cancel");
    Scanner take = new Scanner(System.in);
    int answer = Integer.parseInt(take.nextLine());

    switch(answer) {

        case 1: 
            Game.GuessGame(Card.chooseCard(card1, card2));

    }

    }
```

I thought that it may be because im trying to call a method in the parameters of another method. So I tried calling it from other classes but it still gives the cannot find symbol error.

Thank you.

Comment: `chooseCard` is not a static method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Card.chooseCard(card1, card2)` means calling a static method. You may want to declare `chooseCard` as

```
public static Card choosecard(Card firstCard, Card secondCard)
```

Comment: Highly appreciated =)

Answer (score 0):

`public Card choosecard(Card firstCard, Card secondCard)`

Its not a static method.

`Game.GuessGame(Card.chooseCard(card1, card2));`

But `Card.chooseCard(card1, card2)` means you are calling it statically.

Consider making it static or calling via object.

Comment: Always something silly with my coding. Appreciate the help!